# How can I check if keras/tensorflow is using cuDNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cudnn

I have installed CUDA and cuDNN, but the last was not working, giving a lot of error messages in theano. Now I am training moderate sized deep conv nets in Keras/Tensorflow, without getting any cuDNN error messages. How can I check if cuDNN is now being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr:** If tensorflow-gpu works, then CuDNN is used.

The prebuilt binaries of TensorFlow (at least since version 1.3) link to the CuDNN library. If CuDNN is missing, an error message will tell you `ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed...`.

According to the [TensorFlow install documentation for version 1.5](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), CuDNN **must** be installed for GPU support even if you build it from source. There are still a lot of fallbacks in the TensorFlow code for the case of CuDNN not being available -- as far as I can tell it used to be optional in prior versions.

[Here are two lines from the TensorFlow source that explicitly tell and force that CuDNN is required for gpu acceleration](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c9dbbb898b3b8c3fcb113f5e43bc5a764ee81a8f/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L499-L500).

There is a special GPU version of TensorFlow that needs to be installed in order to use the GPU (and CuDNN). Make sure the installed python package is `tensorflow-gpu` and not just `tensorflow`.

You can list the packages containing "tensorflow" with `conda list tensorflow` (or just `pip list`, if you do not use anaconda), but make sure you have the right environment activated.

When you run your scripts with GPU support, they will start like this:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

2018- ... C:\tf_jenkins\...\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7845
```

To test it, just type into the console:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session()
```

To check if you "see" the CuDNN from your python environment and therewith validate a correct PATH variable, you can try this:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.WinDLL("cudnn64_7.dll") # use the file name of your cudnn version here.
```

Comment: Yes, I have tensorflow-gpu, and it is using the GPU. My question relies on specific usage of cuDNN. As I understand, GPU usage can happen independently of cuDNN, as it is just a GPU-accelerating library with improved libraries for gpu usage right?

Comment: @hirschme Even if you build tensorflow from the sources you have to specify the CuDNN so with current versions, you can't build it without it. It looks like it used to be different with very early versions of tensorflow, but I am speaking of the current one, that is 1.5.

Comment: @hirschme I added some more information to my answer, explaining why I believe that tensorflow-gpu currently does not work without CuDNN. If you are still in doubt, you can try to add a Conv2D-Layer, as the TensorFlow explicitly catches this case with an error: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c9dbbb898b3b8c3fcb113f5e43bc5a764ee81a8f/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L499-L500

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to look into the GPU optimized Keras Layers.

- CuDNNLSTM
- CuDNNGRU

They are significantly faster:
https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnnlstm

We saw a 10x improvement going from the LSTM to CuDNNLSTM Keras layers.

Note:
We also saw a 10x increase in VMS (virtual memory) usage on the machine. So there are tradeoffs to consider.

Comment: It would be better if you included comparisons in your answer to prove _significantly faster_ claim.

Comment: We saw a 10x improvement going from the LSTM to CuDNNLSTM Keras layers.

Comment: @lolbas Not needed. It is common knowledge that the CuDNN implementations are 3 - 10x faster than their loop based counterparts.